# What is the maximum noise value along a line segment in a simplex noise function?

Tags: sampling, noise

Is it possible to find the highest "noise" value along a line segment defined by two endpoints within a Simplex (or Perlin) function by using an equation?

The reason I ask is to avoid expensive ray marching. It's fine if there are multiple points along the segment with the maximum value. It would be preferred if it could work with multiple octaves of Fractional Brownian Motion as well. I'm fairly certain it's possible but it might be too difficult to derive.

Corresponding code for the simplex (snoise) function can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/670c22f3966e662d2f83). I've added a rudimentary image to show what I'm trying to do [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk9U4.png) :P